# Add a custom loss to the autoencoder reconstruction loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder

This is my first post here, so I hope it complies to the guidelines and is interesting also for other people except myself.

I am building a CNN autoencoder that takes as input matrixes of fixed sizes with the goal of getting a lower dimensional representation of them (I call them hashes here). I want to make these hashes similar, when the matrixes are similar. Since just a few of my data are labeled, I want to make the loss function a combination of two separate functions. One part will be the reconstruction error of the autoencoder (This part is correctly working). The other part, I want it to be for the labeled data. Since I will have three different classes, I want that on each batch, to calculate the distance between hash values belonging to the same class (I am having trouble implementing this).

My effort so far:

```
X = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 512, 128, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
class1_indices = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32)
class2_indices = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32)
hashes, reconstructed_output = self.conv_net(X, weights, biases_enc, biases_dec, keep_prob)
class1_hashes = tf.gather(hashes, class1_indices)
class1_cost = self.calculate_within_class_loss(class1_hashes)
class2_hashes = tf.gather(hashes, class2_indices)
class2_cost = self.calculate_within_class_loss(class2_hashes)
loss_all = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(reconstructed_output - X))
loss_labeled = class1_cost + class2_cost
loss_op = loss_all + loss_labeled
optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)
```

Where calclulate_within_class_loss is a separate function that I created. I have currently implemented it only for the difference of the first hash of a class with other hashes of that class in the same batch, however, I am not happy with my current implementation and it looks that it is not working.

```
def calculate_within_class_loss(self, hash_values):
    first_hash = tf.slice(hash_values, [0, 0], [1, 256])
    total_loss = tf.foldl(lambda d, e: d + tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(e, first_hash)))), hash_values, initializer=0.0)
    return total_loss
```

So, I have two questions / issues:

1. Is there any easy way to calculate the distance of every raw with all other raws in a tensor?
2. My current implementation of calculate within class distance, even if it is just for the first element with other elements, will give me a 'nan' when I try to optimize it.

Thanks for your time and help :)

Comment: What is the shape of `class?_hashes`?

Comment: Sorry. I posted only part of the code here that I thought would be relevant to the question. As hashes has a shape [None, 256], the class?_hashes has also shape [?, 256], depending on how many indices of that class I have in the current batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sample code, you are calculating the sum of Eucledian distance between the points.

[image]

For this, you will have to loop over the entire dataset and do `O(n^2 * m)` calculations and have `O(n^2 * m)` space, i.e. Tensorflow graph operations.
Here, `n` is the number of vectors and `m` is the size of the hash, i.e. 256.

However, if you could change your object to the following:

[image]

Then, you can use the [nifty relationship between the squared Euclidean distance and the variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20108/link-between-variance-and-pairwise-distances-within-a-variable) and rewrite the same calculation as

[image]

Where `mu_k` is the average value of the `k`th coordinate for the cluster.

This will allow you to compute the value in `O(n * m)` time and `O(n * m)` Tensorflow operations.

This would be the way to go if you think this change (i.e. from Euclidean distance to squared Euclidean distance) will not adversely effect your loss function.